# Admob Rewarded Video Test Ad Not Loading

Tags: android

I have implemented Admob in my application. I am using Test ads for testing. The **Banner** and **Interstitial TestAds** are working fine, but **Rewarded Video** Ad **is Failing with Code 3**

I don't know, what is wrong. Both are working fine, but Rewarded Video Ad is not loading. 
using **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'** in Gradle.

My Code:

```
mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                 new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(getResources().getString(R.string.MyTestDevice)).build());
```

Answer (score 1):

I used exactly your code and worked fine. You may take a look:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener{
    private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_ad);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                }
            }
        });
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem then? Why it is not showing on my side?